# ¿Como cambiar el tipo de dato double a moneda de visual a excel?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vba, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2010

espero puedan ayudarme, como puedo exportar un texbox con tipo de dato double a excel convertido a moneda mexicana, estoy usando éste formato

```
TXTDESTAJO.Text = Format(TotalDestajo, "$###,##0.00")
```

En visual si me aparece el texbox $45.00 pero al exportarlo a excel me sale XDR45.00 habrá alguna manera de convertirlo o concatenarlo de manera que me apararesca tanto en el formulario de visual como en excel de tipo moneda mexicana

Answer (score 0):

Has probado utilizando Ccur al pasarlo a Excel y luego darle el formato?

```
TXTDESTAJO.Text = Format(Ccur(TotalDestajo), "$###,##0.00")
```

Comment: Como se utiliza el Ccur me da error, hay que importar alguna libreria?

Comment: Hola, es CCur(expresión_numérica). Más info aqui: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions